# 502 Gateway Error on php script

Tags: php, webserver, cpanel, http-error

I am getting the error message

> 502 Bad Gateway
>   The gateway received an invalid HTTP response or unexpected disconnect from the original server.

while running some PHP scripts on my server after some time of their execution(say 30-40 seconds). I checked the error logs in cpanel, but nothing is reflected there.I am sure its not due to my script crashing, as it runs fine on my localhost.I am using shared hosting btw.

P.S.- As some of you are asking , here's the [script](http://pastebin.com/SNjv4HeV) , I am using curl to scrape data about research papers from Microsoft Academic site, its purely for academic purposes.

Comment: If your script runs in the 30 second plus range, running into timeouts is not uncommon. Its not a good practice to run long-running scripts from the browser.

Comment: First, *"I am sure its not due to my script crashing, as it runs fine on my localhost"* is a very wrong statement.

Comment: @datasage, what are the alternatives?

Comment: [This may help](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm).

Comment: ok, here's the script(http://pastebin.com/SNjv4HeV) , I am using curl to scrape data about research papers from Microsoft Academic site, its purely for academic purposes.

Comment: I had the same problem with a script, it was an endless loop.

Comment: You can run php scripts via command line. Depending how they are written it may just be a be a matter of running `php script.php`. Some scripts written within an MVC framework may not work without some modification however.

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue is without more details on the error. As already said, a timeout error is most likely. But on the other hand, an `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` should be displayed in that case. A gateway error is strange. Maybe it has do to with some proxy. Double check the Apache error logs and maybe the system logs.

Comment: Another source of such problems could be, that it isn't allowed to use CURL in PHP. Use `phpinfo()` to check if it is enabled. Or you are not using the right connection options in CURL. But than again, there should be a more detailed error message with PHP ini-setting `display_errors=1` and full error reporting.

Comment: Your server use nginx ? (I think it)
You can post log error of apache?